# Getting transformation configuration from custom processor: Nifi

Tags: etl, apache-nifi

I trying to test a functionality for Nifi. The data I pulled from database consist of specific columns say "id". I need to use Nifi to transform the column name to "customer_id". I understood this is a easy job using something like jolt. But my problem is I need to pull these configuration or rules from somewhere else let say in another database or some other place. I don't want to hard code in the jolt transform to specify the column names instead get it from some other location. Is there any best practice or best way of doing this? Will I have to write any customer processor for this and if so what is the best place to start referring for writing the custom processors?

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways you can do transforms as well as JOLT - it is worth researching using [Records](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) and Schema's in NiFi.

But on to your problem - you could use [LookupRecord](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupRecord/) with LookupServices for pulling the configurations, for example, you could pull them out of a [database](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.lookup.db.DatabaseRecordLookupService/index.html) or from a [REST endpoint](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-lookup-services-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.lookup.RestLookupService/index.html). There are many LookupServices - read the LookupRecord docs page for a list of them.

Comment: So u r saying I can use the Lookup record to pull the configuration or rules and add them directly to nifi processor such as JOLT and apply transforamtion?

Comment: Yes - there is also LookupAttribute that might be useful to you - depends on your flow https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LookupAttribute/